# According to Catholicism, would it be wrong for a husband to intentionally eat in such a way as to decrease fertility?

Tags: catholicism, sexuality, contraception

Contraception is not OK according to the Catholic Church, with the exception of fertility awareness methods (FAMs), which involve abstinence when a woman is in the part of her cycle where she is fertile.

However, there are ways to decrease male fertility, such as getting 'snipped' (a vasectomy), which the Catholic Church says constitutes a mortal sin. A Catholic.com [article](https://www.catholic.com/qa/can-a-catholic-husband-who-has-had-a-vasectomy-receive-communion) states

> "A vasectomy constitutes grave matter. Together with full knowledge of
> the gravity of the action and full and free consent to the action, a
> mortal sin is committed."

What about simply eating in a way that is intended to decrease male fertility, such as going vegan and eating lots of soy, say - according to the Catholic Church, would that also be sinful, and if so, would it constitute a mortal sin or would it be a venial sin?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128943/discussion-on-question-by-one-god-the-father-according-to-catholicism-would-it).

Comment: Related.   https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/41309/23657

Answer (score 10):

St. Alphonsus of Liguori, [*Theologia Moralis* lib. 6, 942, p. 690](https://archive.org/details/theologiamoralis02ligu_0/page/690/mode/2up):

> A husband or wife rendering himself or herself impotent, even by licit means (e.g., fasts, etc.), sins gravely. If one cannot otherwise perform the [[marriage] debt](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=32969), it is licit to not observe the fasts of the Church.
> <sub>Peccat graviter vir vel mulier, si se impotentem reddat, etiam mediis alias licitis, v.gr. ieiuniis etc. invita comparte: imo si aliter non posssit reddere debitum, licite non observat ieiunia ecclesiæ.</sub>

cf. [*ibid.* lib. 3, 1034 §4, p. 768](https://archive.org/details/theologiamoralis01ligu_0/page/768/mode/2up):

> But if the man observing the fasts of the Church, and other moderate [fasts] from devotion, is rendered less potent to render the [marriage] debt, he is not bound to refrain from them; because he is not bound to make himself more potent by lacking spiritual [goods].
> <sub>Si autem vir servans ecclesiæ ieiunia, et alia moderata ex devotione, redderetur minus potens ad debitum reddendum, non teneretur ab eis abstinere; quia non tenetur cum spirituali iactura illa omittere ut potentiorem se reddat</sub>

Impotency ≠ infertility, but they are related. An impotent husband is infertile, but an infertile husband isn't necessarily impotent.

- [Impotence](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34126) (*impotentia coeundi*) means the inability to perform the marital act.
  <sup>A husband or wife invalidly marry if they know they cannot perform the marital act; impotency is [diriment impediment](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33109) to marriage.</sup>
- Infertility or sterility (*impotentia generandi*) means a child does not result from a marital act.

Now, if one intentionally eats a diet to render himself impotent to the extent he becomes infertile, but is still able to perform the marital act, that is no different than *artificial* contraception, condemned in [*Casti Connubii*](https://www.vatican.va/content/pius-xi/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-xi_enc_19301231_casti-connubii.html) §56:

> any use whatsoever of matrimony exercised in such a way that the act is **deliberately frustrated** in its natural power to generate life is an offense against the law of God and of nature, and those who indulge in such are branded with the guilt of a grave sin.
> <sub>quemlibet matrimonii usum, in quo exercendo, actus, **de industria hominum**, naturali sua vitæ procreandæ vi **destituatur**, Dei et naturæ legem infringere, et eos qui tale quid commiserint gravis noxæ labe commaculari.</sub>

Comment: If a man eats a diet that reduces fertility but is still open to having pregnancy occur how is that different from NFP?  Practicing NFP greatly reduces chance of conception but the couple must still be open to a pregnancy occurring. Does Casti Connubii condemn NFP since it deliberately frustrates the power to generate life?

Comment: @Kris Periodic continence is to refrain from the act, not engage in a "deliberately frustrated" act.

Comment: Engaging in the act only at the time when pregnancy is unlikely is deliberately frustrating the natural power to generate life is it it?

Comment: Only engaging in intercourse when it's least likely to result in procreation *absolutely is* a "deliberately frustrated" act. I would further argue that, by this logic, anyone known to have significantly reduced fertility can't get married *at all*. (Well, if "marriage debt" is a thing. At minimum, it would be sinful for such a person to engage in any sexual act.)

Comment: @Kris I think the point is that Casti Connubii forbids so-called 'natural' 'family planning' as promoted today, by forbidding anything which "deliberately" frustrates the ability to concieve — i.e. all contraception, whether it be 'artificial' or 'natural' (what's the difference if the effect is the same), including only having intercourse when you believe you are less likely to concieve.

Comment: @SolaGratia Isn't the response here that there isn't an act which is deliberately frustrated? I.e., there is a lack of an act.

Comment: @SolaGratia Now that the Catholic Church promotes NFP, does it mean  Casti Connubii §56 is no longer in force?  If so, wouldn't this mean that this answer is invalid?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I don't think so, because with NFP no act is deliberately frustrated. Rather, there is simply a lack of an act in certain situations.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I don't think one can say 'the Church promotes' something that it never has, or has traditionally forbidden, simply because today it's allowed. That's more what we do with dogma and established doctrine, not what this or that pope writes in isolation. I think the traditional teaching on marriage is that you space out children naturally by spacing out when you try for a child, not by trying for one when you think you won't get one, purely for sexual pleasure purposes and the bonding that comes with it. I would be slow to call a 'new take' 'the Church.' That's too strong.

Comment: @SolaGratia After reading [this article](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/view.cfm?recnum=6452) about whether NFP is "heretical" in light of *Casti Connubii* by providing background of *Casti Connubii* as well as its misinterpretations decades later.  Let me see if I understand your meaning correctly.  The article says that the "exclusive use of the infertile period" has been a "long and unbroken tradition" and it's licit in itself as long as it's done with "just reasons" based on a response to a query to Pope Pius XI 1.5 years after *Casti Connubii*.  Would you agree?

Comment: @SolaGratia For more on "just reasons" I found a good EWTN article by a seminary professor of moral theology: [Just Cause and Natural Family Planning](https://www.ewtn.com/catholicism/library/just-cause-and-natural-family-planning-9730)

Comment: @OneGodtheFather "there is a lack of an act."  Why can't that be an act?  If I go on a diet to lose weight and skip meals as a part of that diet, am I actually doing anything?  I'm not just not eating lunch, I'm purposefully avoiding lunch.  Whereas if I skip lunch because I was just busy doing something else and it slipped my mind, that seems less like a choice.

Comment: @Ryan_L Right, there's a higher level act here (the decision to abstain while the wife is fertile), and so the question is whether that's right. But you can see the difference in your example. To 'deliberately frustrate' the act of eating lunch would be something like vomiting up your lunch after eating it - even if your purpose is to lose weight. There seems to be something wrong with that, I think, to most people intuitively. But to simply abstain from meals for health reasons? There doesn't seem to be something wrong with that, if indeed it's for health reasons.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I read the article, and I'm somewhat convinced of the interpretation that natural family planning can licitly include — "grave reason" provided — engagement of spouses in the marital act at naturally occurring times when fertility is nigh impossible. However, the author does seem to conflate "periodic continence" with this, and I don't think that's warranted. It technically falls under that, but it's clearly different when you have an additional intention of specifically not having children. The line between that and a c****m for instance, is virtually non-existent.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I think God has left that line blurred for a reason. To make couples more scrupulous about the matter on purpose, in a remedial way. That's my take.

Answer (score 0):

See Mark 7

> <sup>**14**</sup> And when he had called all the people unto him, he said unto them, Hearken unto me every one of you, and understand:
> <sup>**15**</sup> There is nothing from without a man, that entering into him can defile him: but the things which come out of him, those are they that defile the man.
> <sup>**16**</sup> If any man have ears to hear, let him hear.
> <sup>**17**</sup> And when he was entered into the house from the people, his disciples asked him concerning the parable.
> <sup>**18**</sup> And he saith unto them, Are ye so without understanding also? Do ye not perceive, that whatsoever thing from without entereth into the man, it cannot defile him;
> <sup>**19**</sup> Because it entereth not into his heart, but into the belly, and goeth out into the draught, purging all meats?
> <sup>**20**</sup> And he said, That which cometh out of the man, that defileth the man.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it's an interesting and relevant verse. But presumably the sin would involve what's occurring in the husband's heart, here, no? It is not the technical act of eating something, but the intention, which flows from the heart.